# Mapping array of objects to an array of Objects with object and array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object

```
   const response =  {
        "message": "story records found successfully",
        "result": [
            {
                "created_AT": "Thu, 13 Jan 2022 17:37:04 GMT",
                "created_BY": "avinash",
                "dateTime": "Thu, 13 Jan 2022 17:37:04 GMT",
                "deleted_BY": "",
                "flag": 0,
                "project_ID": "infobot1234",
                "stories": {
                    "steps": [
                        {
                            "intent": "test"
                        },
                        {
                            "action": "uttence_test_heading"
                        },
                        {
                            "intent": "fruits"
                        },
                        {
                            "intent": "testintent"
                        },
                        {
                            "action": "utter_txt1234"
                        },
                        {
                            "action": "uttence_test_heading"
                        },
                        {
                            "action": "utter_txt1234"
                        },
                        {
                            "intent": "test"
                        },
                        {
                            "intent": "fruits"
                        },
                        {
                            "action": "uttence_test_heading"
                        },
                        {
                            "intent": "my_localities12333qqqwq"
                        }
                    ],
                    "story": "happy path rdedd"
                },
                "stories_ID": "f5728c4f-3717-40c2-8419-265d5d59bfd1",
                "updated_BY": "",
                "user_ID": "av1234"
            }
        ],
        "status_code": 0
    }
```

From this I have to create a structure like, so my expected output is

```
const data = [
                  {intent: 'test', actions:['uttence_test_heading']},
                  {intent:'fruits', actions:[]},
                  {intent:"testintent", actions:["utter_txt1234","uttence_test_heading","utter_txt1234"]},
                  {intent:"test", actions:[]},
                  {intent:"fruits", actions:["uttence_test_heading"]},
                  {intent: "my_localities12333qqqwq", actions:[]}
                 ]
```

The closest that I could get was using `response.result[0].stories.steps` which gives me the result

```
[{
  intent: "test"
}, {
  action: "uttence_test_heading"
}, {
  intent: "fruits"
}, {
  intent: "testintent"
}, {
  action: "utter_txt1234"
}, {
  action: "uttence_test_heading"
}, {
  action: "utter_txt1234"
}, {
  intent: "test"
}, {
  intent: "fruits"
}, {
  action: "uttence_test_heading"
}, {
  intent: "my_localities12333qqqwq"
}]
```

How can I achieve my expected result do I have to use some condition or something like `Object.keys` and then apply any condition, because for each intent there is an action and if there is no action then it should be an empty array.

How can I achieve my expected result please guide !

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Nitheesh the closest I could get was to get that array of objects using response.result[0].stories.steps

Comment: Its is not a sufficient attempt. Try focusing on javascript loops and arrays. Try to loop through that array anf push to a new array based on the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through each array element using the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) array method, and check if the element is an **intent**. If it is, push a new object to the result array, if it isn't, just push a new element to the actions array of the last index intent using the [`.at()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) method:

```js
const steps = [
  {"intent": "test"},
  {"action": "uttence_test_heading"},
  {"intent": "fruits"},
  {"intent": "testintent"},
  {"action": "utter_txt1234"},
  {"action": "uttence_test_heading"},
  {"action": "utter_txt1234"},
  {"intent": "test"},
  {"intent": "fruits"},
  {"action": "uttence_test_heading"},
  {"intent": "my_localities12333qqqwq"}
];

const result = steps.reduce((acc, e) => {
  if (Object.keys(e)[0] === "intent") {
    acc.push({ ...e, actions: [] });
  }else {
    acc.at(-1).actions.push(e.action)
  }
  
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```